# error incorporating application insights into sign up sign in policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to incorporate applications insights into my SUSI journey as indicated here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights

But I get the error that the JourneyInsights is invalid child node of UserJourneyBehaviours. Below is what I have. I can't remove the ScriptExecution tag as I need it.

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
      <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="key" DeveloperMode="false" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works when I have them in the other order (JourneyInsights first, ScriptExecution after it):

```xml
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="true" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
  <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```